# C# .Net Wait for all threads to complete and get return values

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using the following code to create two threads and wait them to complete:

```
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething(a, b));
Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething(a, b));

Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
```

The DoSomething Method returns has a return type of string and when both of the tasks finish I want to use the return value of it.

I tried creating two string variables, and assign them value returned like:

```
string x, y;
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => x = DoSomething(a, b));
Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => y = DoSomething(a, b));
```

But I get a compile time error that x and y are unassigned, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `Task<string>` instead of a `Task` and querying the `Task<string>.Result`

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to accomplish using `Task.Run`

```
var task1 = Task.Run(() => DoSomething(a, b));
var task2 = Task.Run(() => DoSomething(a, b));
var result1 = await task1;
var result2 = await task2;
```

Answer (score 0):

he says its a compile time error; I am assuming it is blaming for default values.
in your first line, assign the default value for x and y to `null`

```
string x = null;
string y = null;
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => x = DoSomething(a, b));
Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => y = DoSomething(a, b));
```

also after this

```
Task.WhenAll(task1, task2).ContinueWith((tasks)=>{ // access results here});
```

Comment: why the down votes; initially ? :( am sure this is the problem.